# How to read chunks for a text file based on a word as a key delimiter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, file, lodash

I have a .txt file with this format:

```
Part #368 - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Part #369 - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Part #370 - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I read the file like this:

```
var lines = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf-8')
.split('\n')
.filter(Boolean);
```

So it returns an array of the lines of the file. How can I get the chunks of the file starting with the "Part" string?

```
var parts = _.filter(lines,function( s ) { return s.indexOf( 'Part' ) !== -1; });
```

Something like this but instead of getting the strings starting with "Part" I want all the lines from "Part" string to next "Part" string.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf-8').split('Part')` be enough?

Comment: This is a really good use case for a transform stream in Node.js.  The stream will buffer data until the next part, and then emit the entire part as one go.  (Put the readable side of the stream in object mode.)  Best to handle this streaming so that you don't need to buffer the entire file into memory before doing anything.

Comment: @ItaloAyres it works but it cuts the 'Hand' strings.

Comment: @Brad I know it's late but check out my answer. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

## JSON Stream

As per [@Brad's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927439/how-to-read-chunks-for-a-text-file-based-on-a-word-as-a-key-delimiter#comment74887986_43927439), here is a class extended from [`stream.Transform`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream) that delimits the file into a JSON array stream:

```
const { Transform } = require('stream');

class Delimited extends Transform {
  constructor({ delimiter = /\r?\n/g, encoding = 'utf8' } = {}) {
    super();

    // initialize internal values
    this._delimiter = delimiter instanceof RegExp ? delimiter : new RegExp(delimiter, 'g');
    this._encoding = encoding;
    this._buffer = '';
    this._first = true;
  }

  _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    // convert input encoding into output encoding
    // and append to internal buffer
    if (encoding === 'buffer') {
      this._buffer += chunk.toString(this._encoding);
    } else if (encoding === this._encoding) {
      this._buffer += chunk;
    } else {
      this._buffer += Buffer.from(chunk, encoding).toString(this._encoding);
    }

    let partialJSON = '';

    // check if delimiter is found
    if (this._delimiter.test(this._buffer)) {
      // split internal buffer by delimiter
      let sections = this._buffer.split(this._delimiter);
      // put possibly incomplete section from array back into internal buffer
      this._buffer = sections.pop();
      // add each section to partial json array
      sections.forEach(section => {
        partialJSON += `${this._first ? '[' : ','}${JSON.stringify(section)}`;
        this._first = false;
      });
    }

    // push partial json array to readable stream
    callback(null, partialJSON);
  }

  _flush(callback) {
    // add remaining buffer as last section to json array
    callback(null, `${this._first ? '[' : ','}${JSON.stringify(this._buffer)}]`);
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let stream = fs.createReadStream('file.txt', 'utf8');
let transform = new Delimited({ delimiter: /\n\n(?=Part #\d)/g });
let json = '';

transform.on('data', (chunk) => json += chunk);
transform.on('end', () => console.log(JSON.parse(json)));

stream.pipe(transform);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZXfb9MwEMff81ecxKQ4okuRkGCsKpUQe@EBEONhEkWbmzitN9cOtjPWVfnby9n5Ubcrm3hFy0OV2ufv3X18d7mmt9Rkmpf2WKqcbTIljYU1fNdUmkLpJdQwBs1@VVwzEhurGV3GySiKMkGNgY9M8CW3LAd2Z5nMTXByHQF4PV1lVmmyhry11qg5nOrJVA7nA2AyUzmXc1yMK1ucxN7nuk68AoCpSqaJ8@n@DYfAJbecCn7P8BXVJBVwS0XFjLewC27Sy9DX9p1jOFRmTBXwjc3P7kqYBLunINnvdoP0ywOI5y7lrXYQcfcabs@qovB@4zhcLrhGtmNAHsyt1y6hS9vxItmikjdbHAPIqBAzmt10IDB15HnLtMU8yspuySEGBaqy4WJ3hMocaFni5QAa9cCaIL0RL4BsUxpj3M1m3DneS@zlGHysqVXnVuMhsoulZVUDE4Y9VN8zftzHjtTfLD/4t7TQ6gHF5Kkg/a//EcxCSbUrrU/nXz4H99fTX7DsxiUUFJSBQlUy70HuVV9qmbEkDDjZZoySphTc7t8KzFZbF62ti86wzHLsKBjvIEi9yL7nNkHvxdVFqYzhM7FCZ5lalqjHOkFw5IBqTVfgCq6pp0Ol8qDEu5DSUpUkdElznAk0W/Q@ULGlC9cG/3t3rX2vgo1whodId2j8vocFO5eDt351tA4bawLxjxhbOB7E9dHaGaXGXzwvVp1eUl@NerndriwoVli3WffVEfUEzeJA/C4rHIk5nQmk6aejP9G1LpGVEIMw8qRpfV9Ul4VAWXKgzx09zZYURx12TUubGsCha0OieyT33P4LoZ0SrX9etXHWG194PjOkVGqVMWPwHPbQKHJ7/QDDbTc@@09COPBPcd7LqSST8VdEAS@meTKce8xOwmfRtFvUy6VKkjinlsYDaLo6ceXgbbvpgOd37XHKOXNv6b49SrBUqDnxyeItGEacQJK4z0mTVVrykpFeJhltNk2Mr9@cwDFcHH6ii6ef/9Ym6gC9ewb0KKC3r54BHXr@AA)

## String Stream

Alternatively, if you prefer not to transfer the JSON to another file, process, or as a client response, you can emit each section as a chunk by setting the output stream to `objectMode: true`:

```
const { Transform } = require('stream');

class Delimited extends Transform {
  constructor(delimiter = /\r?\n/g) {
    super({ objectMode: true });

    // initialize internal values
    this._delimiter = delimiter instanceof RegExp ? delimiter : new RegExp(delimiter, 'g');
    this._encoding = 'utf8';
    this._buffer = '';
    this._first = true;
  }

  _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    // convert input encoding into output encoding
    // and append to internal buffer
    if (encoding === 'buffer') {
      this._buffer += chunk.toString(this._encoding);
    } else if (encoding === this._encoding) {
      this._buffer += chunk;
    } else {
      this._buffer += Buffer.from(chunk, encoding).toString(this._encoding);
    }

    if (this._delimiter.test(this._buffer)) {
      // split internal buffer by delimiter
      let sections = this._buffer.split(this._delimiter);
      // put possibly incomplete section from array back into internal buffer
      this._buffer = sections.pop();
      // push each section to readable stream in object mode
      sections.forEach(this.push, this);
    }

    callback();
  }

  _flush(callback) {
    // push remaining buffer to readable stream
    callback(null, this._buffer);
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let stream = fs.createReadStream('file.txt', 'utf8');
let transform = new Delimited(/\n\n(?=Part #\d)/g);
let array = [];

transform.on('data', (chunk) => array.push(chunk));
transform.on('end', () => console.log(array));

stream.pipe(transform);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VRNbxMxEL3vrxiJw3pFukFCgtJqqYToEQkBh0oEVc7ubOLWsY3tLS1VfnsYez@STQK9o@4hsew37808z/iG33FXWmH8idIVbkqtnIdH@Ga5crW2K1hDARZ/NsIiS523yFdpdp4kpeTOwUeUYiU8VoD3HlXldiIfE4DIZ5vSa8uqDmuJcTqzFzM1XWQRBeAag5Y9gp7fYOk/USpnQHEI66AVENMpCCW84FL8RloSj@IS7rhs0EWEXwqXX@@qbNeC0uCqRF3DF1xc3hu42Dk9A4W/uoNtmhNIF6HULTeqUldCLYg6bXx9mu4ezpu6jqrpaLsWlhwtYjVhfx3Kufa9S6xcNup2Aj31BEou5ZyXt701VDi5eIfWUxWm8QM0mKBBN353sw/hqgJuDF0JEGiwq00ygkQNbFtQQXm3h2kvvFfYywJirrnXX72lIDY2pXNqDSgdHrLvgf@tMaL6G/JDXOW11QcuZk8lGX8HG/Y6J/foPNuVy7b5krfOSOH3PYX5w7ajOqxED476WdAUQDEqII8k@8pdelEl3KrRzom5fCCxUq8M8WFPCKFu4NbyBwjt0nbDsYs@aNA@pdxow8aSbgnIy@UgQpQ08RWfSxKOw08S3ZTCisa0Cx4oqacviaAtLPBNovrge/zrW7wVD5cRZqKWBGdH2j@mZXHF6QGgburqOExtzK0aKSej0ju19SbeS1tNAcbqEp3LnacGOU/C2TCddBxehuGVY9OZmil2UXzmNI4vZlU2DS0VYtqbKOD7D3qwBoJcK5ZW3PN0Am2TZlC8b8HRnm6TSMYxNLghJKLDI6ol5lIvWIwM8KQtIDfCIBtis/PNps3t9ZtTOIGr419y9fT332KS3qB3zwb906C3r54NOvb9AQ)

Comment: Good in concept, but what's the deal with the last line where you call the callback with some brackets?  And, why would you want to output JSON from this anyway?  Don't make your own JSON serialization, and JSON isn't required here... just output in object mode.

Comment: @Brad the idea is the `_flush()` is called when the writable stream is ended, and so what remains in the internal buffer is the last section since a delimiter was never found in it, therefore it is required to be added in `_flush()` when end-of-stream is verified. And if it isn't serialized, there's very little point in using this transform if you're expecting the entire data to be buffered in memory at the end anyway, you might as well just `.split(delimiter)` at the end of a normal stream in that case. This is more useful for transferring JSON to another file or a client response, etc.

Comment: @Brad I added the `objectMode: true` stream. I'm assuming that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

This creates an array of array of lines.

```
var parts = _.reduce(lines, function( result, line ) {
    if (line.indexOf('Part') !== -1) result.push([]);
    _.last(result).push(line);
    return result;
}, []);
```