# In NodeJS, how would I terminate a stream at a certain string of characters?

Tags: node.js, express, child-process, node-streams

I have an Express route that, when hit, spawns a separate process, then streams the standard output of that process to the user.

I am only interested in the first part of the output of that separate process, and want to end the stream (and close the connection to the user) when the stdout contains a certain set of characters (for example, `-----`).

Here is my ExpressJS code:

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const {spawn} = require('child_process')

router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.type('text')
  const program = spawn(
    './foo',
    {shell: false}
  )

  program.stdout.on('data', (data) => res.write(data))
  program.on('close', (code) => res.end())
  req.on('close', (err) => {
    program.kill(15)
  })
})
```

Here is some example stdout from my process:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Suspendisse molestie porttitor nulla, mattis laoreet arcu ullamcorper vel.
Fusce dapibus mollis dui, vel ornare nulla fermentum quis.
-----
Pellentesque fringilla convallis purus, sit amet laoreet quam ornare eu.
Curabitur ut ultricies urna.
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae
-----
Proin varius laoreet blandit. Proin pulvinar a augue non volutpat.
```

In this example, I would want to stream the following before killing the process and calling `res.end()`.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Suspendisse molestie porttitor nulla, mattis laoreet arcu ullamcorper vel.
Fusce dapibus mollis dui, vel ornare nulla fermentum quis.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made this example for you. I hope is it useful to you :-)

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const rs = fs.createReadStream('./lorem.txt')

let keepReading = true;

rs.on('data', data => {

  if (keepReading) {
    const lines = data.toString().split('\n');
    let selectedText = ''

    for (const line of lines) {
      if (line.includes('-----')) {
        keepReading = false;
      }
      if (keepReading) {
        if (selectedText) {
          selectedText += '\n' + line;
        } else {
          selectedText += line;
        }
      }
    }
    process.stdout.write(selectedText)
  }
})
rs.on('close', code => process.exit(code))
```

Note that `rs` is equivalent to your `program`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My concern with that approach is that it's reading all the data into memory, which causes problems if the stdout is arbitrarily long.

Comment: @zuzak - Why are you thinking it's reading all the data into memory? The event of data is launched for a chunk of the response. And the unique variable I keep is `keepReading`

Comment: Maybe this post can be better than mine at String Stream https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927439/how-to-read-chunks-for-a-text-file-based-on-a-word-as-a-key-delimiter